# Recreating overlapping circles with text in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, intersections

I'm trying to create this image in tikz.

[image]

I've created the basic structure but cant handle the intersections of the circles with each other. I'm sure the `intersections` library needs to be used. I tried many things but didnt come up with a viable solution.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,positioning,calc,intersections,shapes}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
    thick]
        \node(block1)[ellipse,text width=2.5cm,draw,align=left]{Leptons\\Quarks};
        \node(block2)[xshift=2cm,minimum height=5em,ellipse,draw,]{Mesons Baryons};
        \node(block3)[xshift=4cm,ellipse,text width=2cm,draw,align=right]{Photons, Gluons, Graviton, \\ Higgs Boson,\\ Z \& W boson};

        \node[below =0.3cm of block1] {Fermions};
        \node[above=0.3cm of block2] {Hadrons};
        \node[below=0.3cm of block3] {Bosons};

        
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a simple, straight forward way to do it:

- draw circles, with constant and different x- and y radii
- place nodes as labels
- enable multi-line for some of them
- use absolute coordinates

I copied content from your screenshot, which is probably not correct from a physics point of view.

To change fonts add `font={\small\bfseries}` or similar to individual or all nodes styles/options (like `align=center`).

[image: result]

```
\documentclass[10pt,border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}

 \begin{tikzpicture}[
    L/.style={align=center},% style for labels
 ]
    % ~~~ ellipses + circle ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    \draw[fill=orange!50] (-2.2,0) circle [x radius=2, y radius=1.7];
    \draw[fill=yellow] ( 2.2,0)    circle [x radius=2, y radius=1.7];
    \draw (0,0)                    circle [radius=1.7];
    
    % ~~~ labels ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    \node at (0,4) {Disclaimer: as in screenshot, probably incorrect content};
    \node at (0,2) {Hadrons};
    \node at ( 2.2,-2) {Bosons};
    \node at (-2.2,-2) {Fermions};
    
    \node at (-1,0) {Mesons};
    \node at ( 1,0) {Baryons};
    
    
    \node[L] at (2.9,0) {Leptons \&\\Quarks};
    \node[L] at (-2.9,0) {Graviton,\\Higgs boson,\\\\
                         Photon, Gluon,\\\\
                         Z \& $W^\pm$};
 \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: yes, from physics point of view, the fermions and bosons are wrongly placed in the original screenshot. Although i was wondering, can the same thing be done using the instersections library somehow?

Comment: @afaq, it certainly can. I suspect Qrrbirbirbel might post one, soon. // However, you don't need to use intersections. Instead you could also use anchor points of the nodes shape (like block1.west) for relative positioning.